# Disclosing employment in acknowledgement of conference paper

Tags: paper-submission, acknowledgement, conflict-of-interest

I'm a part time PhD student in computer science and work full time at an asset management firm. My paper was accepted into an IEEE conference. However, I have not used any of my work's resource for the paper (though my work could use some of my findings once it's published). Do I still need to disclose my work affiliation in the Acknowledgement section of the final submission and state that there's no conflict of interest?

Comment: https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/conflict-of-interest-questions

Comment: To answer the question "Is there a conflict of interest?", it is necessary to know exactly the relationship between the job at the asset management firm and the content of the paper.  Simply having another job is not something that must be disclosed.

Comment: Thanks. I guess my point is there isn't but my FT job is related to the paper I'm publishing. I'm more interested to know whether it's necessary disclose the relationship? If I do disclose, it will be something along the lines of "XXX is a full time employee of YYY at the time of submission. However, this work is not supported by YYY."

Comment: A case for a disclaimer would be, for instance, if you had demonstrated that the method used by your company is superior to existing methods.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Maybe your comment should be an answer. Even though an accepted answer exists, yours is much better.

Comment: Have you had your paper reviewed by your employer? It probably will have guidance on whether acknowledgement is required. If you haven't, do so. The "my FT job is related the paper I'm publishing" opens you to potential legal action.

Comment: @Louic Statements that not enough information was provided are not answers.

Comment: @Aruralreader I haven't but I've joined 6 months ago. When I joined, I've discussed publishing papers with them and they said as long as it wasn't using company infrastructure/data/methods it was fine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your particular case, your work got accepted at an IEEE conference. Congratulations.

IEEE has a relatively extensive website on [author ethics](https://conferences.ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/author-ethics/). It doesn't seem to mention affiliations at all. Obviously, what you put into the paper should be correct, though.

But what is the role of putting the affiliation on the paper? After all, you speak for yourself, not your organization. It is (1) assigning credit, and (2) to make contacting you easier in case that is needed.

For none of these purposes, the asset management firm needs to be mentioned. It makes sense to declare potential conflicts of interest proactively, but as you wrote, there are none.

Many researchers do other work on the side, such as consulting, a small start-up, giving educational courses, etc. - I've not seen such a declaration of not having a conflict of interest in a (computer science) paper so far.

However, it probably makes sense to check if your main employer is fine with this (or even requires you to not mention them in the paper  - this could for instance be the case if they have no way of checking what you wrote is correct and hence don't want to risk their name being on the paper). Due to reason (2) for putting an affiliation on a paper, I believe it to be OK to put your asset management company as an affiliation on the paper if they insist.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this is very helpful.